# Using php Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

how do I capture, just the names of the animals.

my zoo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zoo>
<animal id="315" name="Lion"></animal>
<animal id="316" name="Cat"></animal>
</zoo>
```

I did the test like this, but it returns empty.

edit.

```
  $html = file_get_html('zoo.xml');
  foreach($html->find('animal') as $animal) {
            $item['name'] = $animal->find('name',0 )->plaintext;
            $animals[] = $item;
        }
        print_r($animals);
```

result

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
        )

)
```

Am I doing the right way?

Comment: `$html->find('zoo')` looks wrong, shouldn't that be `$html->find('animal')`?

Comment: and shouldn't `$animal->find('name')` instead be `$animal->name`?

Comment: @KarstenKoop  `$item['name'] = $animal->find('name')->plaintext; ` ?

Comment: @KarstenKoop Made the change, more still empty. I have now received 2 fields.

Comment: [Relevant reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641). TL;DR: Consider using SimpleXml or DOM instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animal names are in the attributes, you can use [getAttribute](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#api):

```
$html = file_get_html('zoo.xml');
foreach($html->find('animal') as $animal) {
    $animals[] = ['name' => $animal->getAttribute('name')];
}
print_r($animals);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lion
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Cat
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @KarstenKoop e @Thefourthbird got it.

```
   $html = file_get_html('zoon.xml');
      foreach($html->find('animal') as $animal) {
                $item['name'] = $animal->name;
                $animals[] = $item;
            }
            print_r($animals);
```

Thanks